# Difference between findViewById(R.id.content) and getRootView()

Tags: android, view, root

What is the difference between findViewById(R.id.content) and getRootView() ? Don't both return the root view of an activity?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method [`findViewById(R.id.content)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById%28int%29) searches down the view hierarchy for a View with the id `content` (it examines itself as well).

The method [`getRootView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getRootView%28%29) walks up view hierarchy until it hits the root View (it examines itself as well).

If the View you are in has the id `content` and it is the root view then these methods will give the same result, otherwise they won't.